# What technique is used here?

Tags: flash, background

Birthday picture of the British royal family.

It probably ISN'T a green-screen and Photoshop job.  But it sure looks like it is!   What setup and technique might have been involved?

[image]

Comment: what leads you to believe that this is anything other than a straight photo?

Comment: @ths The image does look somewhat unnatural due to the fact the two individuals appear to be in the shade (yet there are soft specular highlights on the man's forehead and appears to be similar highlights on the lady's hair) and the background is not.

Comment: @MichaelC true,  but it would have been interesting to get the OP's reasons, as is standard with "how to achieve this effect" questions.

Comment: @ths The difference in lighting between the people and the background is fairly obvious.

Comment: Re, "...individuals...in the shade..." With no clue in the background to suggest there would be _any_ shady spots anywhere on that lawn. IMO, if the lawn behind the Royal Couple were dappled with shady spots under trees and umbrellas, then it might be easier for our eyes to accept that they were standing _in_ one of those shady spots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm seeing it as a large flag or scrim above them to keep the direct sun off - large flat light, just about for free courtesy of the bright day.
It has broadened but not eliminated shadows & leaves a bit of a pate-shine, which is why I think it's a white, translucent scrim.

Add to that a large front reflector/poly, or it could even be added natural light from another stone pathway & no flash would be required.

Judging from the barely-visible at this resolution catchlights in eyes & shiny buttons, I'm not seeing any small light like a flash, even one with softbox/umbrella.

Eyes & one button…
[image] [image]

*Edit:* I found the original photo, on [PA Media's twitter feed](https://twitter.com/PA/status/1270460663471779840/photo/1), where it looks more likely there's a front flash as fill-in. I'm still sticking to the scrim idea though, for now.

[image]

…and more evidence of an on-camera flash, tight shadow

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think you've nailed it.   I wonder whether the photographer intended that result?  I doubt he had much chance to experiment or try different setups.